# Search string from one file to another and then print the line where it is found in another file

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. I have two files. Suppose the file name is file_1 and file_2. Now i want to take the string from file_1 line by line and want to search it in file_2. If the string found in file_2 then i want to print that whole line where the string found in file_2. I want to write a script for that in python.

This is what i tried to do:

```
    data = open('path//file_2.txt').read()
    for x in open(s.strip() for s in open('path//file_1.txt').readlines()):
           if x in data:
           print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick dirty solution:

```
with open('file_1') as file_1, open('file_2') as file_2:
    for line_1 in file_1:
        line_1 = line_1.rstrip('\n')
        for line_2 in file_2:
            line_2 = line_2.rstrip('\n')
            if line_1 in line_2:
                print(line_2)
        file_2.seek(0)
```

Comment: No, u interpreted it wrong, i have many lines of strings in a file. i want to take those strings one by one from that file and search it in another file. if that string found in another file then i want to print the full line where it's found in another file.